# when electron.net build on win64 and target to linux x64 goes wrong

Tags: .net-core, build, electron, hadoop-yarn, electron.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QV2k.png)

it always reports error:
cannot execute cause-exec: C:\Users\WT\AppData\Local\\electronbuilder\Cache\'apppimage\appimage-12.0.1\linux-x64\mksquashfs": file doesnot exist

i built it success on win64 when target is win64, but fail to linux x64

```
electronize build /target linux
```

i have try to three ways :
1、download appimage-12.0.1 files and copy to "C:\Users\WT\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\appimage" and file mksquashfs is exist
2、change the build image source,like this: npm config set ELECTRON_BUILDER_BINARIES_MIRROR = http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron-builder-binaries/
3、change the npm image source,like this: npm config set registry "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/"

i expect to get a easy and success way to build electron.net projects when target to linux 64